# Does a finite product of commutators of the form $[a,b]$ lie in $A∩B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

1) If $G = A★B$ be the free product of two groups $A$ and $B$, then $A$ and $B$ need not be normal to $A★B$ necessarily, right?

My Aim:

I need to know if finite product of commutators of the form $[a,b]$ with $a ∈ A$ and $b ∈ B$ lie in $A ∩ B$ even without above normality.

My larger Aim:

Consider the free group $\langle G,G\rangle$ freely generated by all pairs $\langle x,y\rangle$ with $x,y ∈ G$. I am trying to prove that given $M =$ the sub group generated by $\{ \langle a,b\rangle \mid a ∈ A/\{1\}, b ∈ B/\{1\} \}$ and $μ ∈ M$ such that $[μ] = 1$, prove that $μ = 1$.

I can prove the above if $A$ and $B$ are normal sub groups of $G$, but unlucky otherwise. Any help?

Comment: What's a “countable product”?

Comment: Free products are, by definition, reduced words on the two groups, but those are finite products by definition. This also gives the commutator relation. By definition $A$ is all words with just symbols from $A$ and $B$ is those with just symbols from $B$. $a_1b_1a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}$ is a reduced word in neither $A$ nor $B$ unless one of $a_1$ or $b_1$ is the identity, in which case it wasn't a reduced word.

Comment: When I used the word countable, I thought I can may be understand in a more general setting. Suppose A and B are any two disjoint groups(possibly infinite), then I may have infinitely many elements of the form [a,b] right? In that setting, does the word countable sound inappropriate? Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: A topology is required to define the product of an infinite number of factors.

Comment: @Adam Hughes:thanks. Could you also explain why can't (a1)(b1)(a1)−1 become b2? Would a correct argument be that suppose they do, then there exists two reduced forms for a single reduced word b2 and this contradicts its uniqueness?

Comment: Yes, by definition of a free product, a reduced word is a finite sequence of alternating elements of $a$s and $b$s, $b_2$, a sequence is equal to another sequence iff each term is the same.

Comment: @user166305 in addition to my previous comment:  you wrote countable product, perhaps you mean to say a "countable collection of products of the form [...]"